# Two types of Markdown files (?) in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, markdown

I noticed that in my Google Drive, some Markdown files are marked with a **blue** icon and **are indexed**:

[image: MD files in Google Drive]

Those with the **icon of [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/)** (which is no longer even integrated into my Drive) are **not indexed** and don't even have the option *Open With > Google Docs* when I right-click them.

What's different about the files? And how do I "fix" all of them to be blue? Missing indexing on most of my text content is a bit of a pain.

Comment: Are the non-indexed files really Markdown files?

Comment: Yep, all are normal Markdown files that I edit using caret.io editor on my desktop.

Comment: I've got a very strange observation. All files uploaded by the desktop GDrive app are marked as the StackEdit ones (non-indexed) but when I open the document on my mobile using iA Writer, edit and save, it will be that blue icon. Maybe iA writer somehow set the MD as a text document while GDrive desktop client doesn't? Why would be Google doing that..

Comment: Sounds like it's an issue with how different programs save their files. I just made a test Markdown file in Windows Notepad and uploaded it to Drive, and it shows it as a non-indexed (non-blue icon) file that can't be natively opened.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the file details for the blue-icon Markdown files and the non-blue-icon files, they probably have different file types.  Below are two `.md` files; the first was saved in Windows Notepad and uploaded, and the second was created in Google Docs.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

It seems like different programs save Markdown files different ways. It may just vary depending on the program.

Comment: Actually, your other file is not a Markdown file: it is a Google Docs document that you named "DriveTest.md", but it will not be downloaded to the desktop as a MD file. In my case, both non-blue and blue are "Text".

Comment: BTW, found this thread: GDrive used to store Markdown files as "Binary". It no longer does that but the indexing is still broken. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/V1RpNJOYjjc;context-place=topicsearchin/drive/markdown